# Financial performance and risk analysis statistics from sample DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, finance

How do I output detailed financial performance and risk analysis statistics from this sample pandas DataFrame?

Can anyone show how this could be done with Quantstats, Pyfolio or another similar approach?

**Code**

```
start_amount = 100000

np.random.seed(8)
win_loss_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([1000, -1000], 543),
    index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2022-01-30", freq="B"),
    columns=["win_loss_amount"]
)
win_loss_df["total_profit"] = win_loss_df.win_loss_amount.cumsum() + start_amount
```

**Sample DataFrame**

```
win_loss_df.head(10)

win_loss_amount total_profit
2020-01-01  -1000   99000
2020-01-02  1000    100000
2020-01-03  -1000   99000
2020-01-06  -1000   98000
2020-01-07  -1000   97000
2020-01-08  1000    98000
2020-01-09  1000    99000
2020-01-10  -1000   98000
2020-01-13  1000    99000
2020-01-14  -1000   98000
```

**Desired output**

I would like to see output including:

- Annual return
- Sharpe ratio
- Max drawdown

I was hoping to use a library for this which would simplify the process and return data similar to a tear sheet.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? have you made attempts, for example, to quantify annual return and your methods failed for some reason ? or you do not know how to calculate annual return, or sharpe ratio, or drawdown ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I can get a lot of this information using Pandas/Numpy but was hoping to leverage one of the packages mentioned to get detailed analytics.  The examples provided with Pyfolio and Quantstats are all for stocks and I'm interested in using custom data similar to my toy example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the profit column and use [quantstats](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats) to generate reports.

##### Code

```
import quantstats as qs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


start_amount = 100000

np.random.seed(8)
win_loss_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([1000, -1000], 543),
    index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2022-01-30", freq="B"),
    columns=["win_loss_amount"]
)
win_loss_df["total_profit"] = win_loss_df.win_loss_amount.cumsum() + start_amount

profit = win_loss_df.total_profit

# Save to image file, this image can also be seen in full report.
qs.plots.yearly_returns(profit, savefig='yearly_return.png')

print(f'montly returns:\n{qs.stats.monthly_returns(profit)}')
print(f'sharpe ratio: {qs.stats.sharpe(profit)}')
print(f'max markdown: {qs.stats.max_drawdown(profit)}')

# Print full report in html.
qs.reports.html(profit, title='ABC', output='', download_filename='profit.html')
```

#### Output

###### Yearly return

[image]

###### Montly returns, Sharpe and markdown

```
montly returns:
           JAN       FEB       MAR           APR       MAY       JUN       JUL       AUG       SEP           OCT       NOV       DEC       EOY
2020 -0.060606  0.000000 -0.064516  4.597701e-02  0.032967  0.000000 -0.010638 -0.010753  0.086957 -1.110223e-16  0.030000  0.048544  0.101444
2021  0.046296 -0.035398  0.045872 -4.440892e-16 -0.026316  0.018018  0.017699 -0.069565  0.018692 -4.587156e-02 -0.057692 -0.030612 -0.117146
2022 -0.042105  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.000000 -0.041881
sharpe ratio: -0.16968348978006012
max markdown: -0.23529411764705888
```

###### Full report

profit.html

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use quantstats. It has a good repertoire of metrics.

Comment: Can you please give an example using the data above?  Thanks