# Quantstats not extending Pandas Attribue

Tags: python, pandas, pip, conda

I am running a simple program in jupyter . even after extending pandas to Quantstats I am getting error" Quantstats does not have DataFrame Attribute" Environment : conda, quantstats was not available on conda so I installed using pip .. is that causing the problem.?

```
import quantstats as qs
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

qs.extend_pandas()

conn = sqlite3.connect("market_data.sqlite")

ticker = "ASIANPAINT.NS"
start_date = "2010-01-01"
end_date = "2022-12-31"

benchmark_ticker = "^NSEI"
benchmark_data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT \* FROM stock_data WHERE symbol = '{}' AND date BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'".format(benchmark_ticker, start_date, end_date), conn)

qs_data = qs.DataFrame(stock_data, benchmark=benchmark_data)

beta = qs_data.beta()
print("The beta of", ticker, "relative to", benchmark_ticker, "is", beta)
```

I have checked dir(quantstats) .. quantstats.extend_pandas() is valid method. Also Pandas have DataFrame attribute so DataFrame is also not an issue

conda list shows following versions installed

| Module | Version | Build | Channel | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Quantstats | 0.0.59 2 | pypi_0 | pypi | (installed using pip as conda was failing to install) |
| Pandas | 1.5.2 | py310h1128e8f_0 |  | ( installed using conda) |

Comment: I'm not following your statement, "Also Pandas have DataFrame attribute so DataFrame is also not an issue". Pandas dataframe doesn't have a keyword of `benchmark` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)) and so with your line `qs_data = qs.DataFrame(stock_data, benchmark=benchmark_data)` you have to be meaning to link to a `qs` ability. What? I think you are combining multiple steps there? Unfortunately, I cannot find a lot of examples, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037499/8508004) uses `pd.DataFrame()` to read in the dataframe

Comment: How was Conda failing to install? The package is available on Conda Forge, i.e., `conda install -c conda-forge quantstats` should work. If not, please [file an Issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/quantstats-feedstock/issues).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you best, and a whole lot other features as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import itertools
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
        
i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]
data_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

for t, url in url_list:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(t, url)
    print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    #writer.writerow([t])
    l = []
    for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
        l.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
        x = list(chain.from_iterable(l))
        d = dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
        d['Index'] = t
        
    data_list.append(d)
```

Result:

```
[{'Index': 'MSFT',
  'P/E': '29.31',
  'EPS (ttm)': '8.99',
  'Insider Own': '0.06%',
  'Shs Outstand': '7.45B',
  'Perf Week': '-0.37%',
  'Market Cap': '2009.81B',
  'Forward P/E': '24.63',
  'EPS next Y': '14.62%',
  'Insider Trans': '-3.47%',
  'Shs Float': '7.44B',
  'Perf Month': '15.19%',
  'Income': '67.45B',
  'PEG': '2.49',
  'EPS next Q': '2.23',
  'Inst Own': '72.40%',
  'Short Float / Ratio': '0.49% / 1.19',
  'Perf Quarter': '15.18%',
  'Sales': '204.09B',
  'P/S': '9.85',
  'EPS this Y': '19.80%',
  'Inst Trans': '0.46%',
  'Short Interest': '36.32M',
  'Perf Half Y': '-8.83%',
  'Book/sh': '24.58',
  'P/B': '10.72',
  'ROA': '18.80%',
  'Target Price': '284.08',
  'Perf Year': '-13.44%',
  'Cash/sh': '13.05',
  'P/C': '20.20',
  'EPS next 5Y': '11.77%',
  'ROE': '39.30%',
  '52W Range': '213.43 - 315.95',
  'Perf YTD': '9.92%',
  'Dividend': '2.72',
  'P/FCF': '49.44',
  'EPS past 5Y': '24.30%',
  'ROI': '31.30%',
  '52W High': '-16.56%',
  'Beta': '0.93',
  'Dividend %': '1.03%',
  'Quick Ratio': '1.90',
  'Sales past 5Y': '15.50%',
  'Gross Margin': '68.20%',
  '52W Low': '23.52%',
  'ATR': '7.66',
  'Employees': '221000',
  'Current Ratio': '1.90',
  'Sales Q/Q': '2.00%',
  'Oper. Margin': '40.50%',
  'RSI (14)': '62.76',
  'Volatility': '3.14% 2.62%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '0.35',
  'EPS Q/Q': '-11.50%',
  'Profit Margin': '33.00%',
  'Rel Volume': '1.30',
  'Prev Close': '266.73',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '0.32',
  'Earnings': 'Jan 24 AMC',
  'Payout': '28.10%',
  'Avg Volume': '30.60M',
  'Price': '263.62',
  'Recom': '1.80',
  'SMA20': '6.72%',
  'SMA50': '7.97%',
  'SMA200': '3.82%',
  'Volume': '39,693,638',
  'Change': '-1.17%'},
 {'Index': 'AAPL',
  'P/E': '25.63',
  'EPS (ttm)': '5.89',
  'Insider Own': '0.07%',
  'Shs Outstand': '15.89B',
  'Perf Week': '0.03%',
  'Market Cap': '2332.30B',
  'Forward P/E': '22.82',
  'EPS next Y': '9.24%',
  'Insider Trans': '-5.52%',
  'Shs Float': '15.83B',
  'Perf Month': '15.41%',
  'Income': '95.17B',
  'PEG': '3.15',
  'EPS next Q': '1.44',
  'Inst Own': '60.10%',
  'Short Float / Ratio': '0.77% / 1.57',
  'Perf Quarter': '8.15%',
  'Sales': '387.54B',
  'P/S': '6.02',
  'EPS this Y': '8.90%',
  'Inst Trans': '-0.47%',
  'Short Interest': '121.87M',
  'Perf Half Y': '-10.85%',
  'Book/sh': '3.57',
  'P/B': '42.26',
  'ROA': '27.50%',
  'Target Price': '168.90',
  'Perf Year': '-13.70%',
  'Cash/sh': '3.32',
  'P/C': '45.42',
  'EPS next 5Y': '8.13%',
  'ROE': '163.50%',
  '52W Range': '124.17 - 179.61',
  'Perf YTD': '16.12%',
  'Dividend': '0.92',
  'P/FCF': '28.23',
  'EPS past 5Y': '21.60%',
  'ROI': '58.30%',
  '52W High': '-16.00%',
  'Beta': '1.31',
  'Dividend %': '0.61%',
  'Quick Ratio': '0.90',
  'Sales past 5Y': '11.50%',
  'Gross Margin': '43.10%',
  '52W Low': '21.50%',
  'ATR': '4.18',
  'Employees': '164000',
  'Current Ratio': '0.90',
  'Sales Q/Q': '-5.50%',
  'Oper. Margin': '29.40%',
  'RSI (14)': '62.53',
  'Volatility': '3.18% 2.61%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '1.96',
  'EPS Q/Q': '-10.30%',
  'Profit Margin': '24.60%',
  'Rel Volume': '0.71',
  'Prev Close': '151.92',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '1.76',
  'Earnings': 'Feb 02 AMC',
  'Payout': '15.40%',
  'Avg Volume': '77.84M',
  'Price': '150.87',
  'Recom': '2.00',
  'SMA20': '5.59%',
  'SMA50': '8.49%',
  'SMA200': '2.20%',
  'Volume': '54,936,229',
  'Change': '-0.69%'},
 {'Index': 'AMZN',
  'P/E': '-',
  'EPS (ttm)': '-0.27',
  'Insider Own': '9.80%',
  'Shs Outstand': '10.22B',
  'Perf Week': '-12.99%',
  'Market Cap': '1094.49B',
  'Forward P/E': '38.54',
  'EPS next Y': '177.07%',
  'Insider Trans': '-0.02%',
  'Shs Float': '9.25B',
  'Perf Month': '9.31%',
  'Income': '-2722.00M',
  'PEG': '-',
  'EPS next Q': '0.21',
  'Inst Own': '60.10%',
  'Short Float / Ratio': '0.74% / 0.84',
  'Perf Quarter': '9.18%',
  'Sales': '513.98B',
  'P/S': '2.13',
  'EPS this Y': '-108.20%',
  'Inst Trans': '0.56%',
  'Short Interest': '68.55M',
  'Perf Half Y': '-31.15%',
  'Book/sh': '14.29',
  'P/B': '6.87',
  'ROA': '-0.60%',
  'Target Price': '137.66',
  'Perf Year': '-39.14%',
  'Cash/sh': '6.29',
  'P/C': '15.63',
  'EPS next 5Y': '46.00%',
  'ROE': '-2.00%',
  '52W Range': '81.43 - 170.83',
  'Perf YTD': '16.95%',
  'Dividend': '-',
  'P/FCF': '-',
  'EPS past 5Y': '-26.00%',
  'ROI': '6.60%',
  '52W High': '-42.49%',
  'Beta': '1.23',
  'Dividend %': '-',
  'Quick Ratio': '0.70',
  'Sales past 5Y': '23.60%',
  'Gross Margin': '43.80%',
  '52W Low': '20.64%',
  'ATR': '4.24',
  'Employees': '1544000',
  'Current Ratio': '0.90',
  'Sales Q/Q': '8.60%',
  'Oper. Margin': '2.40%',
  'RSI (14)': '50.32',
  'Volatility': '4.41% 3.88%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '0.61',
  'EPS Q/Q': '-98.00%',
  'Profit Margin': '-0.50%',
  'Rel Volume': '0.78',
  'Prev Close': '100.05',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '0.58',
  'Earnings': 'Feb 02 AMC',
  'Payout': '-',
  'Avg Volume': '81.41M',
  'Price': '98.24',
  'Recom': '1.80',
  'SMA20': '-1.41%',
  'SMA50': '5.87%',
  'SMA200': '-11.68%',
  'Volume': '63,824,436',
  'Change': '-1.81%'}]
```